# How to make jScrollPane's scroll bar longer than the visible area of scrolling content?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I'm, working with jScrollPane jQuery plugin. I want to make the scrolling content disappear 20  pixels lower than the top edge of the scrollbar, and 20 pixels higher than the bottom edge of the scrollbar.

Could someone please explain how this can be done?

This example shows the text floating outside of the length of the scrollbar:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/caps.html

What I want is exact opposite: the scrollbar somewhat longer than the visible area of the text.

Would appreciate your advice!

P.S.If it's technically impossible, I would be grateful if someone could suggest a "duct tape" solution.

Dimitri Vorontzov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible without changing the library and how it renders the scroll bar.  It's rendered *inside* the div that contains the text.  So if you make it bigger it would disappear like the text.  If you try to position it absolute and z-index it above, it does all kinds of funky things to the css.  So, if you really need this, you have to dig into the code and change it.  I'd advise just to position the stuff around it to get a similar effect though.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up "positioning the stuff around it", as you suggested.